# How do I change a wpf chart to a fixed size?

Tags: charts

I'm new to stackoverflow.

I want to know how to stretch a graph to a fixed size. The X axis will not always have the same number of values. Sometimes there is 3 datapoints or 2000, it depends. The Legend of the graph and the graph itself is out of proportion. Can someone please give me some advice. Thank you in advance.